# How to restore PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-18.04, psql, pg-dump, pg-restore

I'm working in project with a CMS called tendenci using PostgreSQL (it is required) in Ubuntu, and I had to migrate from a Virtual Machine to the production server. But I faced a problems with migrating the database.

I used this command to extract data from VM:

```
pg_dump -Fc mydb > db.dump
```

but when I tried to import data to my server with this command

```
psql -d mydb --file=db.dump
```

this error shows up

```
The input is a PostgreSQL custom-format dump.
Use the pg_restore command-line client to restore this dump to a database.
```

and when I use `pg_restore` command no errors show up, but the database doesn't get restored.

```
pg_restore -C -d mydb db.dump
```

Comment: sorry i mean no errors

Comment: How do you restore it with pg_restore ? The syntax is I use is: pg_restore -C -d template1 db.dump

Comment: i used this three command and no one of them did the job 1. pg_dump -Fc mydb > db.dump  2. pg_restore -C -d postgres db.dump  3. pg_restore -d newdb db.dump

Comment: You can try running the pg_restore with  -v and see what the output says.

Comment: i waited for this command to give an output almost 15 minute but there is no output

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name `-C` is `--create`, not `--clean` (that would be `-c`). I would understand the behavior with `-c` if someone is connected to the database that is about to be dropped. It would be helpful to see the contents of `pg_stat_activity` and `pg_locks` while the restore is hanging.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: ah, right...

Answer (score 0):

To move the complete database cluster, including all users etc., use the following commands:

$ pg_dumpall >all-db.sql

and then on the target server initialize an new and emppty database cluster, start it, and then run

$ psql -f all-db.sql

Run the pg_dumpall and psql commands as the postgres user.